# Average in SQL Server with null value multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to take average of multiple columns such that if there is null value then ignore that and take remaining value as take average.

For example if I have `10,NULL` as values then I want 10 as average, I don't want the null value to be considered as 0 and then take average as 10+0 -> 5, I want the average to be 10.

This is a dummy table, I have multiple columns like Month1.... Month 1000 and I don't want to hardcode any values while calculating average by dividing the number of column.

My output from this query is wrong:

```
CREATE TABLE Dummy_tab 
(
    empid int,
    Month1 int,
    Month2 int,
    Month3 int,
);
 
INSERT INTO Dummy_tab 
VALUES (1, NULL,10, 20), (2, NULL,NULL, 20), (3, 10,20, 30);
  
SELECT
    empid,
    AVG(Month1 + Month2 + Month3)
FROM
    Dummy_tab
GROUP BY 
    empid
```

Snippet for the desired output along with what my output is coming

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible option is to use `VALUES` table value constructor - to unpivot the columns into rows and to calculate the average value for all columns, excluding the columns with `NULL` values:

Statement:

```
SELECT t.empid, c.Average
FROM Dummy_tab t
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT AVG(v.Month) AS Average
   FROM (VALUES (t.Month1), (t.Month2), (t.Month3)) v (Month)
) c
```

Result:

```
empid   Average
1       15
2       20
3       20
```

Comment: I like this one... simple :)

Comment: @shawnt00 Why would it triplicate rows?  And can you be more specific about what you mean by "mess with other aggregations you got going on"?

Comment: I wasn't reading close enough. The whole time I had been thinking that the average was taken across both rows and columns and I hadn't noticed the average was done inside the `cross apply`.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with integers and division you need to cast either the numerator or denominator to a decimal value before doing the division.

For the average of three values in a single row:

```
SELECT
    empid,
    (
        -- coalesce(MonthX, 0) would work too
        CASE WHEN Month1 IS NULL THEN 0.0 ELSE Month1 END +
        CASE WHEN Month2 IS NULL THEN 0.0 ELSE Month2 END +
        CASE WHEN Month3 IS NULL THEN 0.0 ELSE Month3 END +
    ) * 1.0 /
    (
        CASE WHEN Month1 IS NULL THEN 0.0 ELSE 1.0 END +
        CASE WHEN Month2 IS NULL THEN 0.0 ELSE 1.0 END +
        CASE WHEN Month3 IS NULL THEN 0.0 ELSE 1.0 END
    ) AS Average
FROM
    Dummy_tab
GROUP BY 
    empid;
```

Or more generally you could apply this to a group with multiple rows. `SUM()` handles the nulls values automatically:

```
SELECT
    empid,
    (SUM(Month1) + SUM(Month2) + SUM(Month3)) * 1.0 /
        (COUNT(Month1) + COUNT(Month2) + COUNT(Month3)) AS Average
FROM
    Dummy_tab
GROUP BY 
    empid
```

Comment: The 1st query is not working , the second one is giving wrong output

Comment: Yeah, it ended up doing a multiplication rather than division. Try that. First one was just typos from copying and pasting some of the lines.

Comment: @Dexter_1234, I thought you wanted an average across both rows and columns. I see now that you're just looking to average three values in a single row.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do what you are trying to accomplish:

```
SELECT
    empid,
    (SUM(ISNULL(Month1,0)) 
        + SUM(ISNULL(Month2,0)) 
        + SUM(ISNULL(Month3,0)))
     / 
    (ISNULL(COUNT(Month1),0)
        + ISNULL(COUNT(Month2),0)
        + ISNULL(COUNT(Month3),0)
    )
FROM
    Dummy_tab
GROUP BY 
    empid
```

Answer (score 0):

Shawnt00s code work, if you correct his typo.

```
SELECT
    empid,
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN Month1 IS NULL THEN 0.0 ELSE Month1 END +
        CASE WHEN Month2 IS NULL THEN 0.0 ELSE Month2 END +
        CASE WHEN Month3 IS NULL THEN 0.0 ELSE Month3 END 
    ) /
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN Month1 IS NULL THEN 0.0 ELSE 1.0 END +
        CASE WHEN Month2 IS NULL THEN 0.0 ELSE 1.0 END +
        CASE WHEN Month3 IS NULL THEN 0.0 ELSE 1.0 END
    ) AS Average
FROM
    Dummy_tab
GROUP BY 
    empid
```